# Submit button in php mysql table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

What i have:

```
<table class="sortable table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>CPU</th>
    <th>Speed</th>
    <th>Cores</th>
    <th>TDP</th>
    <th>Preformace</th>
    <th>Overclocing</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Buy</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php $i=0 ;
    do {
    $preformace = $row_Procesory['Preformace'];
    $over = $row_Procesory['Overclocing'];
    $i++; ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['CPU']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['Speed']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['Cores']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['TDP']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#progressbarP$i').height(10).progressbar({
                                    value : 1
                                    });
    $('#progressbarP$i .ui-progressbar-value').animate(
    {width: '$preformace%'},{queue: false});
    });
    </script>
    <div id='progressbarP$i' title='$preformace'></div>  
    ";?></td>

    <td><?php echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#progressbarO$i').height(10).progressbar({
                                    value : 1
                                    });             
    $('#progressbarO$i .ui-progressbar-value').animate({
        width: '$over%'
        }, 1000);
    });
    </script>
    <div id='progressbarO$i' title='$over'></div>  
    ";?></td>

    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['Price']; ?></td>
    <!-- BUTTON SECTION -->
   <td><?php echo "<button class='btn btn-success' type='button' align='CENTER'>Add</button>";?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Procesory = mysql_fetch_assoc($Procesory)); ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Basically im looping through mysql and displaying rows. In preformace and overclocking column im displaying animated jquery progresbar with value from mysql. Im also using bootstrap and sortable.js to make table sortable.

[How it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVxP2.png)

What i want:
When i click add button the name of the processor will be sended to test.php as a variable.
i don't even know how to target name element with jquery :D

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle so we can help more

Comment: its dynamic from my mysql server it would be simple table in jsfiddle

Comment: yes I know, but it would be easier to test it as HTML & JS anyway take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right here is something can help

```
<table class="sortable table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>CPU</th>
    <th>Speed</th>
    <th>Cores</th>
    <th>TDP</th>
    <th>Preformace</th>
    <th>Overclocing</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Buy</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php $i=0 ;
    do {
    $preformace = $row_Procesory['Preformace'];
    $over = $row_Procesory['Overclocing'];
    $i++; ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['CPU']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['Speed']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['Cores']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['TDP']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#progressbarP$i').height(10).progressbar({
                                    value : 1
                                    });
    $('#progressbarP$i .ui-progressbar-value').animate(
    {width: '$preformace%'},{queue: false});
    });
    </script>
    <div id='progressbarP$i' title='$preformace'></div>  
    ";?></td>

    <td><?php echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#progressbarO$i').height(10).progressbar({
                                    value : 1
                                    });             
    $('#progressbarO$i .ui-progressbar-value').animate({
        width: '$over%'
        }, 1000);
    });
    </script>
    <div id='progressbarO$i' title='$over'></div>  
    ";?></td>

    <td><?php echo $row_Procesory['Price']; ?></td>
    <!-- BUTTON SECTION -->
   <td><?php echo "<button class='btn btn-success pro_btn' processor = '".$row_Procesory['CPU']."'  type='button' align='CENTER'>Add</button>";?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Procesory = mysql_fetch_assoc($Procesory)); ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

That solution (**processor attribute**) is to avoid selectors which can be something else we can provide it if you want it

```
$('.pro_btn').die('click').live('click',function(e){
     var name = $(this).attr('processor');
     $.post('test.php',{'processor_name':name}, function(response) {
    // log the response to the console
         console.log("Response: "+response);
     });

});
```

**If you don't want to use the attribute you can do something like this**

```
var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
```

I hope this can help :)

Comment: thanks man i'll try it tomorrow. i didn't know that i can make my own attributes.

Comment: No you can, tell me the result tomorrow

Comment: While you can make your own attributes, it's not recommended. HTML5 has reserved `data-XXX` for user-defined attributes, you should use this. jQuery supports this using the `.data()` method: `$(this).data('processor')` is equivalent to `$(this).attr('data-processor')`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your comment, I know that , I showed two ways just because of HTML5 and thanks for the great info you just provided

Comment: @Sedz great it works i used `data-processor='$Procesor'` atribute and then `$(this).data('processor');` thanks Barman and Sedz

Answer (score 0):

Capture click event and find the closest 'tr' and then the first 'td' of that 'tr'. That would be like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
```

Or get the paren of your button, that will be the td, and them td's parent. That would be the tr. Last get the first td.

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('td:first').text();
```

Or just add an additional attribute to your button and then get the value.

```
$(this).attr('processor');
```

Comment: No, his was several minutes before yours. You can't tell it now, because SO rounds the times. But I would never make such a comment if your answers were within 2 minutes of each other.

Comment: Don't know, When i start answer this question there wasn't any answer. But Whatever, next time before submit an answer will refresh the question.